# Is it possible to define String Inputs in Dymola for an FMU Export?

Tags: xml, string, input, dymola, fmi

I have the problem that after defining an user-defined connector:

```
connector StringInput = input String "input String";
```

following error comes after trying to export the Model to an FMU:

```
"Failed to generate XML file for the FMU or for variable dependencies"
```

Does it mean that the String Input is not used? Or what does the variable dependency means?

I tried FMI 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0. Also I tried connecting the String Input to another String Output (like a shortcut).

Answer (score 2):

String connectors are not supported by Dymola. We have however improved the error message to make that more clear.